# How to obtain json reponse from http request?

Tags: java, android, json

When trying to retrieve the response json from my api I can only ever get a string value which I am unable to convert to jsonobject to use.

Should respond with json format {"result":"success","client[id]":"1"}

But I am only able to retrieve string "result=success,client[id]=1"

```
public void createWHMCSUser(final String emailID, final String random, final String uid) {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String e = URLEncoder.encode(emailID, "utf-8");
                String r = URLEncoder.encode(random, "utf-8");
                URL url = new URL("http://create.user.com/includes/api.php?action=AddClient&username=abc123&password=abc123&accesskey=abc123&firstname=User&lastname=Name&email=" + e +"&address1=na&city=na&state=na&poscode=00000&country=US&phonenumber=0000000000&password2=" + r + "&reponsetype=json");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);



                Log.i("STATUS", String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));
                Log.i("MSG", conn.getResponseMessage());

                if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200){
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                    String readAPIResponse = " ";
                    StringBuilder jsonString = new StringBuilder();
                    while((readAPIResponse = in.readLine()) != null){
                        jsonString.append(readAPIResponse);

                        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString.toString());
                        int aJsonString = obj.getInt("Client[id]");
                        SetClientID(uid,aJsonString);



                    }

                    in.close();


                }

                conn.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    thread.start();

}
```

Comment: It could be that your URL is wrong. Maybe "responsetype" should be "responseType". I recommend using a tool like Postman https://www.getpostman.com/ to manually test the responses you are getting, to see if they match what your code is getting.

Answer (score 1):

use this way more easier and fast 
for more examples and to built library check this : 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking)

```
 AndroidNetworking.get("URL")
                     .setTag("test")
                     .setPriority(Priority.MEDIUM)
                     .build()
                     .getAsJSONObject(new JSONObjectRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                          // handle your response here 

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError error) {
                          // handle error
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you give an example of how to handle the response? Cause I keep getting an exception.

Comment: from your example  {"result":"success","client[id]":"1"}
String result = response.getString("result"); // contain ' success '

Answer (score 0):

Use the json library  to add the java object to JSONObject. That will store all the java object content in to json string format in  your server code. That will convert In to json format.

Then  you will return the  code from server as the regular string.

In the client side, you will receive it as the string.

Then you need to convert it to java object from the json string. That is the actual json string. You will  e able to convert that string to  java obj.

But what you have return is not the json String. That is just string only.